# Android socket run in gingerbread but not in jelly bean

Tags: android, sockets

From this code i can transfer files with my PC in android 2.3.3.(Dell Streak) but when I Run the same code in android 4.2 (Samsung GS 3 ) It does nothing. I think the problem is when the Socket is to initialize ? What I have to do this get working in 4.2?

```
package com.hrandika.synchronizer.serverClient;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class Client {

File sendingFile;

public Client(File sendingFile) {
    Log.d("Client", "Cleint : Constructed");
    this.sendingFile = sendingFile;
}

public void send(String ip) {
    try {
        Log.d("Client", "Cleint stating ....");
        Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 5555);
        Log.d("Client", "Cleint Socket Okay");

        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                outputStream);

        Log.d("Client", "Cleint ready to sent");
        outputStreamWriter.write(sendingFile.getName() + "\n");
        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        Log.d("Client", "Cleint Sent");

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                inputStreamReader);

        String serverResponse = bufferedReader.readLine();

        if (serverResponse.equals("READY")) {
            Log.d("Client", "Cleint : server ready");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) sendingFile.length()];
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sendingFile);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new   BufferedInputStream(
                    fileInputStream);
            bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            outputStream.flush();
            bufferedInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
            socket.close();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}



public class Sender extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        send("192.168.43.21");
        return null;
    }

} 
} // End class Client
```

Comment: use e.printStackTrace(); under the catch to see if this code giving any error?

Comment: How do you instantiate and start `Sender`? Blind guess: you call `doInBackground()` yourself (which is `AsyncTask` misuse) and thus cause `NetworkOnMainThreadException` ?

Comment: it shows this        11-28 17:17:52.890: W/System.err(20565): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0):

You must not perform any networking on UI thread, and this is enforced by the platform starting with Honeycomb. I suppose you're not using `AsyncTask` correctly.

Mandatory reading:

- [Keeping Your App Responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)
- [Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

**Update:** as of networking error, start `adb shell` (I assume the device is connected to your PC via USB) and type `telnet 192.168.43.21 5555` - this way you will be able to check if your server is actually reachable from the phone.

**Update 2:** Just checked, I'm afraid `telnet` binary is not available on stock (not rooted) devices. But any application that can connect to a given IP/port is sufficient for testing, e.g. this [telnet client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=koushikdutta.telnet). This way you can eliminate setup problems, before even touching your own code.

Comment: my bad i have created the Asyn Task I have fix that but i get this error now in android 4.2(work perfectly in 2.3)     java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.21 (port 5555): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)

Comment: Well, are you sure 192.168.43.21 is available on the network your device is directly connected to? Sounds like a setup problem.

Comment: it work perfectly in android 2.3 but not in 4.2 is there special thing to do with 4.2?. so i'm sure 192.168.43.21 is available

Comment: No, I don't think 4.2 needs anything unusual. Do you mind describing your network setup?

Comment: the pc is listing to port 5555 . the phone is sending to the port 5555 the pc ip is 192.168.43.21. both the phone and the pc connected to same wi-fi router.

Comment: the problem was in my router.when i create portable hots pot from my s3 it worked perfectly.thanks for your attention